# Check what values are there in a column in r?

Tags: r

I have created a feature set which has the ground truth in {0,1} i.e Bernoulli. But when I try the following code to train a model:

```
  gbm(data$GT ~ .
      , data = data
      , distribution = "bernoulli"
      , n.trees=100
      , interaction.depth = 8
      , n.minobsinnode = 20
      , shrinkage = 0.1
      , bag.fraction = 0.5
      , train.fraction = 0.8
      , verbose = T)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in gbm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, distribution = distribution, w = w,  : 
Bernoulli requires the response to be in {0,1}
```

I am pretty sure that the responses are in {0,1} but still I want to check whether there is some missing value or something other than {0,1}. How to check that? Otherwise, can there be some other reason of error?

Comment: `str(data$GT)` ?  `unique(data$GT)` ?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the most informative way is `table(x, useNA = "always")`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see which particular values are the issue, you can do something like :

```
data$GT[which(data$GT>1)]  # gives you the values
which(data$GT>1)           # gives you he indexes
```

and so on for any other constraint you want to check.